# How can use Thymeleaf with Cyrillic keywords (token)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf, cyrillic

How can use Thymeleaf with Cyrillic keywords (token) my settings is:

config:

```
@Bean
 public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
     SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
     StringTemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
     templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver);
     return templateEngine;
 }
```

class:

```
public class TemplateConverter {

private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

private final static String TEMPLATE_LOCAL = "RU";

public String getTemplateFromAttributes(String template, Map<String, Object> attr) {
    Context context = new Context(new Locale(TEMPLATE_LOCAL));
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(attr)) {
        attr.forEach((k, v) -> context.setVariable(k, v));
    }

    return templateEngine.process(template, context);
    }
}
```

works:

```
//..
String template = "Привет [(${keyword})]";
String result = templateConverter.getTemplateFromAttributes(template, Map.of("keyword", "мир"));
System.out.println(result); // "Привет мир"
```

But when I try make it with cyrillic words it don't works

```
//..
String template = "Привет [(${ключевое_слово})]";
String result = templateConverter.getTemplateFromAttributes(template, Map.of("ключевое_слово",   "мир"));  // exception
System.out.println(result);
```

**UPDATE**

```
00:47:07.123 [main] DEBUG org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
00:47:07.196 [main] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][main] Exception processing template "Привет [(${ключевое_слово})]": An error happened during template parsing (template: "Привет [(${ключевое_слово})]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "Привет [(${ключевое_слово})]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parse(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:180)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.AbstractTextTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractTextTemplateParser.java:92)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
    at ru.mm.util.converter.TemplateConverter.getTemplateFromAttributes(TemplateConverter.java:35)
    at ru.mm.util.converter.TemplateConverterTest.whenPutRightStringThenRightPlainText(TemplateConverterTest.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
...
```

**UPDATE**

all stac trace
[docs.google.com](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vFSCnGlEIeAwr5V0K2M7UnKYzEz3OKIWjHB-FuHQPm8/edit?usp=sharing)

**TEMPLATE_LOCAL = "RU"** - not effect
**StringTemplateResolver** doesn't have something for setup UTF-8 key

**UPDATE - !!SOLUTION!!**

changed maven dependency
from:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and change engine SpringTemplateEngine -> TemplateEngine

```
config:
  
    @Bean
     public TemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
         TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
         StringTemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
         templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver);
         return templateEngine;
     }
```

Comment: `// exception` - What exception is that? You can show us the full stack trace (as formatted text) in the question.

Comment: Thank you. Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: no that is not , SOF doesn't let me put more :(

Comment: @andrewJames updated, added url on full stack trace
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vFSCnGlEIeAwr5V0K2M7UnKYzEz3OKIWjHB-FuHQPm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am sorry but the stack track needs to be added to the question. Also, can you show us the Spring config properties for your Thymeleaf? (I cannot recreate your issue, right now. Your code works OK for me.)

Comment: @andrewJames Hmm I don't put any property settings for it.. Could you tel me please wich setings do you used ?

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace. Not a link.